I have two graphqql queries in a component. I want second query to execute only after first query is executed and I get data from it. How to proceed?
I have two graphql queries first one is getUser and second one is getChatHistory. I want getChatHistory to execute only after getUser is executed and user details are fetched.
export const getChatHistory = gql`{
   chatHistory {
     title
   }
  }
`;

export const getUser = gql`{
   user {
     name
     email
   }
  }
`;

const Home = ()=> {
  const {loading: chatLoading,error:chatError,data:chatData}=useQuery(getChatHistory);
  const {data:userData} = useQuery(getUser);
  ...


You can't do that in a single component using useQuery since it's a hook and a hook can't be called conditionally - make a separate nested component that grabs the chat history and don't render it until you've got the user.

It is possible. Based on useQuery hook signature
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getChatHistory);
I assume you are using apollo-client? If so, useQuery has skip option, designed for the cases like this.
Here is how you can use it to start fetching chat history only when user has laready fetched (within single component):
export const getChatHistory = gql`{
   chatHistory {
     title
   }
  }
`;

export const getUser = gql`{
   user {
     name
     email
   }
  }
`;

const Home = ()=> {
  const { data: userData } = useQuery(getUser);
  const {
    loading: chatLoading,
    error: chatError,
    data: chatData
  } = useQuery(getChatHistory, {
    // will not start fetching untill user is present
    skip: !userData?.user // or !userData?.getUser?.user depends on the response shape
  });
  ...


getChatHistory won't start fetching until user is there.
For other api clients:

In urql similar setting called pause.
tanstack-query has enabled.


Interesting workaround!
